# Parse TimeSpan with DataRowExtension

Tags: c#, casting, timespan

I want to take value of field from DataRow as TimeSpan (Format like mm:ss) with DataRowExtension but it gives me System.InvalidCastException, as you can see below

```
var time = staffItems.Rows[0].Field<TimeSpan>("TIME_DURATION"); // System.InvalidCastException
```

but when a take this value as string and after Parse to TimeSpan there is no problem occurs.

```
var time = staffItems.Rows[0].Field<string>("TIME_DURATION"); // time : 0:43
var time2 = TimeSpan.Parse(time); // time2 : 00:43:00
```

And the question is, how can i do it with DataRowExtension without any extra parsing or casting.

Comment: `Field<TimeSpan>` *casts* a value that's already a `TimeSpan`. It's equivalent to `(Timespan)`. It doesn't parse, that's why it fails with string content

Comment: You say that i have to take value as string and after cast to TimeSpan, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably TIME_DURATION field comes as vharchar or something else from DataTable. It is have to be equivalent to TimeSpan.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to parse then get time part

```
var time = TimeSpan.Parse(staffItems.Rows[0]["TIME_DURATION"]);
var time2 = time.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

if you want it from datarowextension. You have to create your datatable and specify time object for the "TIME_DURATION" column. You can do this by this approach:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //
        // Loop over DataTable rows and call the Field extension method.
        //
        foreach (DataRow row in GetTable().Rows)
        {
            // Get first field by column index.
            int weight = row.Field<int>(0);

            // Get second field by column name.
            string name = row.Field<string>("Name");

            // Get third field by column index.
            string code = row.Field<string>(2);

            // Get fourth field by column name.
            DateTime date = row.Field<DateTime>("Date");

            // Display the fields.
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", weight, name, code, date);
        }
    }

    static DataTable GetTable()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable(); // Create DataTable
        table.Columns.Add("Weight", typeof(int)); // Add four columns
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Code", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        table.Rows.Add(57, "Koko", "A", DateTime.Now); // Add five rows
        table.Rows.Add(130, "Fido", "B", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(92, "Alex", "C", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(25, "Charles", "D", DateTime.Now);
        table.Rows.Add(7, "Candy", "E", DateTime.Now);
        return table;
    }
}
```

Comment: staffItems.Rows[0] has many column, do you aggree with TimeSpan.Parse(staffItems.Rows[0]); will work ?

Comment: I have edited the code and add ["TIME_DURATION"] part

Comment: I think, staffItems.Rows[0]["TIME_DURATION"] and staffItems.Rows[0].Field<string>("TIME_DURATION") are similar and your solution is same with my example and i found it actually. I dont want to use this solution. and the question is how can i do it with DataRowExtension without any extra parsing or casting

Comment: I think you say what you say without trying the code ı have written. You have to search and look difference between cast and parse operations. You can not cast a date or time object from string. But you can parse this string and convert it to time object. One more thing if you want it from datarowextension. You have to cretae your datatable and specify time object for the "TIME_DURATION" column. You can chehk this link => https://www.dotnetperls.com/datarow-field

Comment: The true answer is "One more thing if you want it from datarowextension. You have to cretae your datatable and specify time object for the "TIME_DURATION" column." and you can see this answer on comment under the question. Thanks..

Comment: Please set as answered for others use.

Answer (score 0):

The below method will parse a `string` to a `TimeSpan` in a `DataRow` extension method.

```
public static TimeSpan ExtractTimeData(this DataRow row, string column)
{
    // check column exists in dataTable
    var exists = row.Table.Columns.Contains(column);

    if (exists)
    {
        // ensure we're not trying to parse null value
        if (row[column] != DBNull.Value)
        {
            TimeSpan time;

            if (TimeSpan.TryParse(row[column].ToString(), out time))
            {
                // return if we can parse to TimeSpan
                return time;
            }
        }
    }

    // return default TimeSpan if there is an error
    return default(TimeSpan);
}
```

And you can use it like:

```
TimeSpan time = row.ExtractTimeData("TIME_DURATION");
string timeString = time.ToString(@"h\:mm");
```